# Why does a non-data descriptor with a __delete__ method hijack attribute writes?

Tags: python, descriptor

A *data descriptor* in Python is an object which implements both `__get__` and `__set__` methods of the descriptor protocol. This definition is given in the ["Descriptor HowTo Guide"](https://docs.python.org/3.6/howto/descriptor.html#descriptor-protocol), and is implemented in the [`inspect.isdatadescriptor`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/inspect.html#inspect.isdatadescriptor) function.

Therefore, `DescrDelete` is a non-data descriptor. However, it seems to hijack the attribute writes as if it was a data descriptor:

```
>>> class DescrDelete:
...     def __delete__(self, instance): pass
...
>>> class A:
...     attr = DescrDelete()
...
>>> instance = A()
>>> instance.attr = 42
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: __set__
```

For comparison, `DescrSet` (also a non-data descriptor) does not exhibit this behaviour:

```
>>> class DescrGet:
...     def __get__(self, instance, value): pass
...
>>>
>>> class A:
...     attr = DescrGet()
...
>>> instance = A()
>>> instance.attr = 42
```

Comment: What's the point of a descriptor you can only delete?

Comment: I knew the descriptor how-to had it wrong, but it really sucks that `inspect.isdatadescriptor` has the wrong check too.

Comment: Grr, if this has been known since '15, why nobody did a PR fixing the inconsistency?

Comment: Actually according to the definitions in the guide instances of `DescrDelete` are descriptors (they have one of the methods) but they are neither data descriptors (they do not have both `__get__` and `__set__`) nor non-data descriptors (they do not have `__get__`)

Comment: There is an open issue: https://bugs.python.org/issue32400

Comment: Here are [two](https://bugs.python.org/issue32400) [relevant](https://bugs.python.org/issue26103) bug reports, including one with a pull request that seems to be in limbo.

Comment: The duplicate covers why this is a data descriptor, but it doesn't quite cover why the descriptor hijacks writes as well as deletion. (It doesn't hijack reads; if you insert an `'attr'` key into an instance `__dict__` directly, the descriptor won't take over reads of `instance.attr`.) The reason it hijacks writes is because writes and deletion both go through the same `tp_descr_set` hook at C level. Implementing `__delete__` causes Python to set a `tp_descr_set` hook, which then gets triggered for both writes and deletion.

Comment: hmm... checking through my old answer again, it looks like I actually covered most of that already.